# Generate AST from C source code using Clang

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

As an academic project, I have to create a front-end for a static analyser. I am new to C/C++ and my main language is Java. 
Initially I have to use Clang to generate an AST for the input C program. Then I need to create the corresponding CFG where after I will do some other tasks. I am struggling to find any good examples or tutorials of how to generate an AST of a C program. Any thoughts or suggestions of how should I approach this project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this list](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html). Also, libclang may be what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find a way to generate a CFG with libclang. Though, it was very useful to understand the process of parsing the source code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Post that includes links to Clang AST tutorials and related posts:

http://variousburglarious.com/2017/01/18/getting-started-with-clang-refactoring-tools/

Repository of Clang AST examples, mostly refactoring and analyzing using AST matchers. Nothing to do with CFG, but maybe it will help?

https://github.com/lanl/CoARCT

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. 
I have also found a good presentation from a lecture:
[Program Analysis with Clang](http://swtv.kaist.ac.kr/courses/cs492-fall17/coverage/lec8-building-Clang-analyzer.pdf)

Comment: The top link no longer exists.